# Entity Framework SaveChangesAsync is not available

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm just trying to clarify something.  We are using EF 6.4.4 in an old web forms project which we're working to upgrade to .net core in the future.  We currently have mvc worked into a lot of it to make it easier, but have a long way to go.  Anyway, we're also trying to make all of our calls async and while we have many EF async methods available to us such as `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `SaveChangesAsync` isn't available.  I'm guessing this is because we're not using the .net core version of EF.  Does anyone know if that's correct?  If not, what assembly would we have to reference to get that method?

Comment: What is your target framework version?

Comment: .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: SaveChangesAsync is only available for net core or EF7

Comment: Maybe you are still referring to the .net 4.0 version, check your .csproj

Comment: Ok thanks.  That was my suspicion - needing .net core.